# Distributing Favorites to all Internet Explorer installations in local network

Tags: group-policy, internet-explorer

I am managing a company with 150 Windows machines.

I would like to manage a central list of Favorites (hyperlinks with a text description) which is automatically synced with each Internet Explorer instllation on each machine.

Either under a dedicated submenu in the Favorites list called "Company Links" or something, or under some toolbar button or similar mechanism.

Is this possibly at all? Can it be done via an Exchange server, which we are running?

Comment: I'm very curious - what do you think Exchange has to do with IE on your workstations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can easily be done via a GPO.

See the TechNet article for how to do this, but it is pretty easy if you understand GPOs already:

[Manage Favorites and Links](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772139.aspx)

SPECIAL THING TO NOTE ON THAT PAGE:

> To delete existing links: If you are a corporate administrator, select
>   the Delete existing Favorites and Links, if present check box to
>   delete the items on the users' Favorites and Links lists. You should
>   use this setting with caution because it removes, among other links,
>   the items that your users added.

Don't get careless and check that box if you value your job. :)

Comment: He's got Exchange, so he's got a domain.

Comment: indeed...thanks @mfinni I didn't read his last sentence...although odd.

Answer (score -1):

This *can* be done, but wouldn't it be easier to put the links on an html page and make it the users' home page in IIS?  That would take a lot of pain out of worrying whether or not some update process runs and touches all those machines every time you want to add, remove, modify, or delete one of those favorites.

Keep it simple :)

Comment: Use GPO to set workstation behavior is a long-settled best practice in windows administration. it's not complex and not painful.

Comment: What IIS has to do with this is beyond me...but forcing a homepage on user's, even a corp intranet, is often a little too draconian for people to accept.